# Bootstrap 5 - several columns with normal width but one that takes up the rest of the space

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, col

If I have a scenario using Bootstrap 5 like...

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-auto">
    <div class="col">One</div>
    <div class="col">Two</div>
    <div class="col">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All columns currently take whatever width their content needs.

I want column two to be as wide as it can be without interfering with the display of columns one and two.

Is this possible with Bootstrap alone or would I need to rely on additional CSS styling?

Comment: I'm thinking that it might only be possible without extra CSS if the width of the other 2 columns is defined Eg `class="col-3"`. In my mind, column 2 is then going to take up the remaining space if you leave that as `class="col"`. Not sure how neatly this would all look when it comes to responsiveness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the answer. Make all columns EXCEPT the one I want to take up all the space col-auto. Make that one class="col".

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto">One</div>
    <div class="col">Two</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```